# How to call GetProcessAffinityMask from Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I tried to use the below code snippet to call GetProcessAffinityMask in the windows api.

```
var 
  procaffmask, 
  sysaffmask       : DWord;
begin
  GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess, procaffmask, sysaffmask);
end;
```

Upon compilation I got the following error message......

> [dcc32 Error] UnitfrmMain.pas(54): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

The C++ syntax for the API call is below:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessAffinityMask(
  _In_  HANDLE     hProcess,
  _Out_ PDWORD_PTR lpProcessAffinityMask,
  _Out_ PDWORD_PTR lpSystemAffinityMask
);
```

So then I changed the `DWORD` to a `PDWORD` but that did not fix it.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? I see Delphi code samples around the internet that do not use pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the declaration of `GetProcessAffinityMask()` in Delphi's `Winapi.Windows` unit:

```
function GetProcessAffinityMask(hProcess: THandle;
  var lpProcessAffinityMask, lpSystemAffinityMask: DWORD_PTR): BOOL; stdcall;
```

`DWORD` and `DWORD_PTR` are different data types.  `DWORD_PTR` is not a "pointer to a DWORD", it is actually a "pointer-sized DWORD" (4 bytes on a 32bit system, 8 bytes on a 64bit system).  Whereas `DWORD` is always 4 bytes on both 32bit and 64bit systems.  Microsoft uses the `P` prefix to indicate a pointer to a type, and uses the `_PTR` suffix to indicate the type itself is dependent on the byte size of a pointer.

The Delphi declaration is using `var` parameters, so you have to match the data type exactly:

```
var 
  procaffmask, 
  sysaffmask       : DWORD_PTR;
begin
  GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess, procaffmask, sysaffmask);
end;
```

Even your quote of the C++ declaration shows that the parameters are `PDWORD_PTR` (pointer to `DWORD_PTR`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, thank you for the explanation of the naming conventions. I see I need to increase my understanding of data types and also it was helpful see the Delphi declaration. I had to match the type declaration EXACTLY, including case. DWord_Ptr would not work.  Many thanks for taking time. to help me.

Comment: See [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx). Also, Delphi is not a case-sensitive language.  `DWord_Ptr` and `DWORD_PTR` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of DWORD use SIZE_T, there will be no error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted many years ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.